# How to deserialize xml objects back to a class list

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datagridview

I am trying to create a windows form application where I create a list of vehicle class objects in a business class list. When a new Item is added to the list, the file is serialized. I have created a class called Vehicle that contains the xml attributes, a method for adding a new instance of the vehicle class, and a way to serialize the data to an xml file. I would like to close the application and reopen it to display this data in a view such as a datagridview. The issue I am currently having is that Im not sure how to deserialize the data back into the class list and display it. When I exit the application and open it again then try and add new vehicles, it overwrites the current data in the xml file.

Here is my Business class with my serialization method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace VehicleSystem
{
    public class Business
    {
        private static List<Vehicle> _vehicleList = new List<Vehicle>();

        public static List<Vehicle> VehicleList
        {
            get => _vehicleList;
        }

      
        public static void Save()
        {
            XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Vehicle>));
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\data.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                serial.Serialize(file, VehicleList);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the vehicle class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace VehicleSystem
{
    [XmlType("vehicle")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Vehicle
    {
        private int _cost;
        private int _year;
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private string _registration;

        [XmlElement("Registration")]
        public string Registration { get => _registration; set => _registration = value; }
        [XmlElement("Model")]
        public string Model { get => _model; set => _model = value; }
        [XmlElement("Make")]
        public string Make { get => _make; set => _make = value; }
        [XmlElement("Year")]
        public int Year { get => _year; set => _year = value; }
        [XmlElement("Cost")]
        public int Cost { get => _cost; set => _cost = value; }

        public Vehicle(string registration, string model, string make, int year, int cost)
        {
            Registration = registration;
            Model = model;
            Make = make;
            Year = year;
            Cost = cost;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the creation of a vehicle:

```
Business.VehicleList.Add(new Vehicle("ABC123","Hilux","Toyota", 1992, 123));
Business.Save();
```

This is what the xml data looks like

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    
-<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    -<vehicle>
        <Registration>ABC123</Registration>
        <Model>Hilux</Model>
        <Make>Toyota</Make>
        <Year>1992</Year>
        <Cost>123</Cost>
    </vehicle>
</ArrayOfVehicle>
```

How might I deserialize this data back to my `VehicleList` and display it into a datagridview?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to put into a dataset and then make table zero the DataSource of a DGV.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication189
{   
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);
 
        }
 
    }
```